# Convert 64-bit Hex to nanoseconds timestamps

Tags: timestamp, base64, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, datetime-conversion

I have timestamps that are represented in 64-bit hex. Is there a way to convert it to nanosecond timestamps? (preferably in c++)

Comment: Can you give an example? Are you sure the source data has nanosecond precision? (for example, Java has 64-bit timestamps, but those are in milliseconds). Also, the Base64 tag is confusing.

Comment: Well, this is an example of what I mean: 1461108575.550984737. It is represented in 16 hex digits, and I'd like to find a way to convert these 16 hex digits to the form of nanoseconds.

Comment: are you sure those are hex digits? Not just decimal? Especially with the dot in there? Floating point hex?

Comment: The number I just put is decimal with seconds on the left hand side and subseconds on the right hand side. I have the hex representation for this timestamp, but I need a way to convert from hex to something similar to the number above.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

I used std::hex to convert a hex value to long, which in turn gives me the nanosecond precision.