# How to get nano second granularity from hex time?

Tags: perl, hex

I am trying to convert hex time(getting first output from kernel module) into nanosecond granularity,

```
580a9272.0a9ce167
```

and I am trying to convert it using perl into human readable format:

```
while (<>) {
s/^([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\.)([a-fA-F0-9]+)(\s+.*)/sprintf("%s%s%s%s",&$converter(hex($1)), $2, hex($3), $4)/oe;
} continue {
print;
}
```

output : Fri Oct 21 18:10:58 2016.178053479

Converter uses localtime() and gmtime() directly
I want time with nano granularity and then year.Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Would this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731370/convert-64-bit-hex-to-nanoseconds-timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36731370/convert-64-bit-hex-to-nanoseconds-timestamps)

Comment: the link tells about doing it in c++, I am using perl to convert, i am very close but missing on last bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`POSIX::strftime` doesn't support fractional seconds, so you need to build the output in parts.

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $opt_gmt = 1;
my $hex = '580a9272.0a9ce167';

my ($s, $ns) = map hex($_), split /\./, $hex;
my $formatted_ns = sprintf("%09d", $ns);
my $formatted = strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.$formatted_ns %Y",
    defined($opt_gmt) ? gmtime($s) : localtime($s));

say $formatted;  # Fri Oct 21 22:10:58.178053479 2016
```

DateTime has native support for nanoseconds, so that presents an alternative.

```
use DateTime qw( );

my $opt_gmt = 1;
my $hex = '580a9272.0a9ce167';

my ($s, $ns) = map hex($_), split /\./, $hex;
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $s );
$dt->set_nanosecond( $ns );
$dt->set_time_zone( defined($opt_gmt) ? 'UTC' : 'local' );

say $dt->strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%N %Y");  # Fri Oct 21 22:10:58.178053479 2016
```

Comment: I am using: if (defined($opt_gmt)) {
    # GMT always wins.
    $converter = \&my_gmtime;
} elsif (defined($opt_local)) {
    # localtime requested.
    $converter = \&my_localtime;
} else {
    # Default is localtime.
    $converter = \&my_localtime;
}

Comment: Adjusted accordingly. It's really weird that `$opt_gmt = 0;` causes UTC to be used, though.

Comment: just a follow up ,can it be done without using any other module? but the core??

Comment: Yes, See the first half of my answer. It only uses core Perl.